# Apache nao encontra URL

Tags: angular, apache, url

Desenvolvi minha pagina usando o angular

Só que ao dar o `ng build --prod --bh=/projeto/`

Quando eu quero acessar meu sistema enviando um parâmetro via url

O mesmo só funciona se estiver usando o provider

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

No qual eu acessaria assim

```
  http://localhost/projeto/#/parametro
```

Eu gostaria de acessar sem precisar precisar usar o HashLocationStrategy, mas quando eu tiro e dou um `ng build --prod --bh=/projeto/`,  e tento acessar sem a estratégia hash, assim:

```
  http://localhost/projeto/parametro
```

Ele dá Not Found

```
The requested URL /projeto/parametro was not found on this server.
```

Mas ao acessar apenas assim

```
http://localhost/projeto/
```

Ele acha

Como faço para acessar sem precisar o do hash.

Meu apache já está ativado

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Como alternativa ao `HashLocationStrategy` você pode implementar essa regra de reescrita no seu `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Quando o `ng build --prod --bh=/projeto/` dá isso aqui `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` No servidor, mas se eu tirar o `--prod`, funciona